# Drawing an image on a window using GFL SDK in MFC

Tags: mfc

I want to load an image and want to draw it on a window in OnPaint of CMainFrame. Can any body tell me how can we achieve this using XnView's gfl library.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about this library, but 20 seconds of Google shows that you should use one of http://www.xnview.com/wiki/index.php/GFL_Windows_specific to convert your image data to an HBITMAP, then use BitBlt() to copy that onto your window (you can find a lot of examples on how to do that everywhere, but in short you do CDC dc; dc.CreateCompatibleDC(); dc.SelectObject(your_bitmap); paintdc.BitBlt(dc, etc);  )